# Does aliasing make any difference on thread safety?

Tags: java, pointers, reference, thread-safety, alias

The following code accesses a variable by downcasting it first, and I'm wondering if it makes any difference if the return type of the method returns the same alias as the one I'm working with (`ContainerPieceVolumesBinding binding`), or the one that is passed in as a method parameter.

I've tested the code, and it seems to be working well, the problem is that there could be a second access point to the same variable (this second access point is optional).

This second access point, in theory would be working with the viewBind alias and not the downcasted version I'm working with here.

Would it make any difference if instead of returning the same alias thrown by the method parameter, I return the downcasted version, would it be safer?

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public ViewDataBinding setData(ViewDataBinding viewBind, @NonNull String bindingTag) {
    
    BindingVisitorsBaseAdapter adapter = new BindingVisitorsBaseAdapter(
            TAG
    );
    adapter.setCompletePendingBindings(
            pendingBindings
    );
    //This is the downcasted alias
    ContainerPieceVolumesBinding binding = (ContainerPieceVolumesBinding) viewBind;
    binding.pieceVolumesContainer.setAdapter(adapter);
    observer = new ObjectNotifier(
    ) {
        @Override
        public Notifier onNotified() {
            return (response, responseType) -> {
                switch (responseType) {
                    case SUBMIT_LIST :
                        List<BindingVisitor> pieceVolumes = (List<BindingVisitor>) response[0];
                        ((BindingVisitorsBaseAdapter)binding.pieceVolumesContainer.getAdapter()).submitList(pieceVolumes);
                        break;
                    case QUANTITY_CHANGE:
                        onQuantityChanged.onChanged(getValues(binding.pieceVolumesContainer));
                        break;
                }
            };
        }
    };
    observer.notifyResponse(SUBMIT_LIST, new ArrayList<>());
   // returning the original version here
    return viewBind;
}
```

Comment: Unless you are referencing a static method through an object call, upcasting and downcasting won't make a difference the safety of the call

Comment: Since you tagget this as "pointers" and based on the question it sounds like you assume similar behavior to C / C++ where `MyClass copied = original` actually creates a copy. However, that is not the case in Java. In Java you are working with references (which you can imagine being like pointers) so as written by @ControlAltDel a cast has no effect, both variables are still referencing the same single object instance. Also note that testing whether something is thread-safe or not is not (easily) possible because thread-safety issues can be rare and are often not consistently reproducible.

Comment: @Marcono1234 it does actually have an effect on static method calls

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are referencing a static method through an object call, upcasting and downcasting won't make a difference the safety of the call

```
public class A {
  public void foo() {
    System.out.println("A");
  }
  public static void bar() {
    System.out.println("As"); 
  }
}

public class B extends A {
  private void foo() {
    System.out.println("B");
  }
  public static void bar() {
    System.out.println("Bs"); 
  }
}

A var = new B();

var.foo(); //will print B
var.bar(); //will print A

((B)var).foo(); //will print B 
((B)var).bar(); //will print B
```